# Passing in DateTime objects to do diff calculations

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP issue

I want to pull in a datetime field from a form- `shift_start` and compare it to the value `shift_end` which is also a datetime, and compute the difference in hours.  This is all in my controller.  I have tried using the constructor `$start = new DateTime($this->shift_start)`to store the value of `shift_start` and different variations of this, including setting manually after with `$start = $this->shift_start`but to no avail.

We want to call `$difference = $start->diff($end)` but foe whatever reason when we run it we get blank values or zeros.

Any insight would be helpful.

UPDATE: changed it so shift_start and shift_end are simply strings in the proper format.

```
        $start = strtotime($this->shift_start);
        $end = strtotime($this->shift_end);
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
        $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Comment: Show us the code you're trying

Comment: You could also circumvent using datetime diff by converting the times to timestamps using strtotime(), subtracting the time stamps, then converting it to hours by dividing by 60 * 60.

Comment: This is a variation of what I have been trying..I changed the code a bit so that the fields that take in hours are just strings in the proper format, but to no avail.  I still want to pass in 'H:i:s' and calculate difference between two objects, but for some reason having trouble properly creating new DateTime objects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not using strtotime properly

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->shift_start));
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->shift_end));
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

**EDIT**

Since you are working with G:i:s, then you need to do this

```
$shift_start = "05:05:05";
$shift_end = "10:10:10";
$start = date('G:i:s', strtotime($shift_start));
$end = date('G:i:s', strtotime($shift_end));
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
var_dump($difference->format('%h')); //prints string(1) "5"
```

Comment: Can you paste the output you get? also, the content of shift_start and shift_end

Comment: nothing actually happens...i dont get an error, but I am expecting to have some value other than 0 in 'hours_worked'.  I used this code      $start = date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->shift_start));                                            
   $end = date('H:i:s', strtotime($this->shift_end));                                                          
   $datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
   $datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
   $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);



   $this->Shift->set('hours_worked', $difference->h);

Comment: please, paste the output of var_dump($this->shift_start); and also var_dump($this->shift_end)

Comment: both? shift_end and shift_start produce string(8) "05:05:05"? Then it is obvious the difference is 0.

Comment: sorry. no. the other one produces  string(8) "10:10:10"

Comment: Now my variable hours_worked stores no value...i used $this->Shift->set('hours_worked', var_dump($difference->format('%h'))); but to no avail

Comment: really? don't you see the error there? use $this->Shift->set('hours_worked', $difference->format('%h')); 

The var_dump was just for showing you my results

Answer (score 0):

A datetime field doesn't have to be converted in order to use it with PHP's DateTime functions. You can directly pass in the `Y-m-d H:i:s` formatted string into it. For example, by using the `field` method in your model:

```
# app/Model/Shift.php
public function duration($id) {
    $start = new DateTime($this->field('shift_start', array('id' => $id));
    $end = new DateTime($this->field('shift_end', array('id' => $id));
    return $start->diff($end);
}
```

This will return a DateInterval object with all the diff info between the start and end time of a certain shift (identified by `$id`). You can then access that data from your ShiftsController like this:

```
# app/Controller/ShiftsController.php
public function view($id) {
    // Check if the shift exists
    if (!$this->Shift->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Unknown shift #' . $id));
    }

    // Get it's data
    $shift = $this->Shift->findById($id);

    // And the duration
    $duration = $this->Shift->duration($shift['Shift']['id']);
}
```

Comment: when i try this, i get "call to undefined method field"

Comment: @johnsmith Then you are not putting that method in your Shift model, but more likely in your Controller. Edited the answer with comments that shows what goes where.